# How to read innodb log file?

Tags: mysql, innodb, logging

I would like to see "general query log" from innodb log file, so is there anybody know how to see / read those query logs?

I tried MySQL admin  utility, it shows only error log and query log is disabled.

Comment: I found this article which solved my problem [link](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-read-mysql-binary-log-files-binlog-with)

Answer (score 7):

The answer is that you **can not**.

The ib_logfile* files do not contain queries, but rather 512-byte aligned instructions on how to re-apply changes made by queries.  For example:

> [Space-id] [Page-id]
>   [Where-in-the-page-to-modify]
>   [Payload]

- Space-id is the file number (e.g. ibdata1 = file number zero).
- Page-id is which page within that file.  All pages are 16K.

Comment: Morgan, do you have the source of this information?

Comment: i want to see the queries run / set of instructions sent to mysql using ib_logfiles and ibdata1. how is that possible? any parser or extraction tool?

Answer (score -1):

Logging queries is a big performance overload, hence it is disabled by default. If you want to log queries then set log variable in my.cnf

```
log=/tmp/mysql.log
```

It is not recommended if your application is live as it will slow it down really hard and users might get 500 or connection timeout errors. Once you are done debugging comment it.

Comment: I actually have log files, ib_logfile0, but i need to see the last, say, 4 days queries. So my question is how to see them